# Many to many relation scaffolded view generates error _id1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, many-to-many

The application I'm working on generates an error while creating an instance of a model. I have Product and Color (many to many) and ProductImage (many ProductImage to a ProductColor).

```
public partial class ProductColor
{
    public ProductColor()
    {
        this.ProductImages = new HashSet<ProductImage>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DefaultValue(0),DisplayName("Price Offset")]
    public Decimal PriceOffset { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int ColorId { get; set; }

    public virtual Color Color { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductImage> ProductImages { get; set; }
}

public partial class ProductImage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("File name"),
      Required(),
      StringLength(255)]
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public bool Default { get; set; }
    public int ProductColor_Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ProductColor ProductColor { get; set; }
}

public class testContext : DbContext
{
    public testContext() : base("name=testContext")
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Manufacturer> Manufacturers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProductColor> ProductColors { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Color> Colors { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProductImage> ProductImages { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
            .HasMany(c => c.ProductColors);
    }    
}
```

After scaffolding the controller and views for ProductImage and going to the index of ProductImage I get an error trying to get ProductImages from the db context.
No wonder because Entity decided the following sql should be used to get the instances:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[FileName] AS [FileName], 
[Extent1].[Default] AS [Default], 
[Extent1].[ProductColor_Id] AS [ProductColor_Id], 
[Extent1].[ProductColor_Id1] AS [ProductColor_Id1]
FROM [dbo].[ProductImages] AS [Extent1]
```

ProductColor_Id1 does not exist in the database. Here is the sql that created the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProductColors] (
    [Id] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PriceOffset] decimal(7,2)  NOT NULL,
    [ProductId] int  NOT NULL,
    [ColorId] int  NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProductImages] (
    [Id] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FileName] nvarchar(255)  NOT NULL,
    [Default] bit  NOT NULL,
    [ProductColor_Id] int  NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProductColors]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_ProductColors]
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC);
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProductColors]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_ProductColorColor]
    FOREIGN KEY ([ColorId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Colors]
        ([Id])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
CREATE INDEX [IX_FK_ProductColorColor]
ON [dbo].[ProductColors]
    ([ColorId]);
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProductColors]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_ProductColorProduct]
    FOREIGN KEY ([ProductId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Products]
        ([Id])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
CREATE INDEX [IX_FK_ProductColorProduct]
ON [dbo].[ProductColors]
    ([ProductId]);
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProductImages]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_ProductColorProductImage]
    FOREIGN KEY ([ProductColor_Id])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[ProductColors]
        ([Id])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
CREATE INDEX [IX_FK_ProductColorProductImage]
ON [dbo].[ProductImages]
    ([ProductColor_Id]);
```

The database is generated from an Entity diagram and looks fine to me. I have no idea why on a ProductImage create it added ProductColor_Id1 in the select statement.

Hope there is enough information provided and that this is a general mistake that's easily solved. Thank you for reading this and hope you can help.

I would like the scaffolded controller and views to work in listing, creating, editing and deleting the ProdcutImage objects but as it is it's not even possible to create one with the information provided to Entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deleting and re creating the association in the Entity diagram I ended up with a ProductImage having ProductColorId instead of ProductColor_Id.

Not too sure what I did differently (maybe checked the "Add foreign key properties to ProductImage entity" in the diagram.

Re created database from diagram and re created model classes from database (to be used in another project). The ProductImage now looks like this:

```
public partial class ProductImage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("File name"),
      Required(),
      StringLength(255)]
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public bool Default { get; set; }
    public int ProductColorId { get; set; }

    public virtual ProductColor ProductColor { get; set; }
}
```

As far as I can see the only difference is ProductColerId, must be a convention in Entity to specify relations this way.

A tip when working in the diagram:

In a one to many first click the one side (in my case one ProductColor has many ProductImage so I right click on ProductColor). Then when choosing add new => association it automatically sets ProductColor (the clicked item) to one. Now setting the many relation on the right side will automatically check the "add foreign key" checkbox.

If I were to click on the many side first (right click on ProductImage). Then change the left side dropdown to many and right side select ProductColor with one for multiplicity then the "add foreign key" check box needs to be checked manually.